# Tengo un problema con imprimir datos en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo una tabla y no se imprime los datos, no se si me puden ayudar soy principiante
la version de mi laravel es Laravel Framework 7.29.2
Mi controllador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::latest()->get();

        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        return back();
    }
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        $user->delete();
        
        return back();
    }
}
```

Y mi index es este, creo que el error esta mas en el html que en otra cosa pero realmente no estoy seguro

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($users as $user)

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                <td>Opciones</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Lo raro es que no me da ningun error y si me imprime la tabla pero sin datos, y la base de datos tiene datos insertados pero lo que no entiendo es el por que no me llama nada.

Comment: ¿Y si estás mandando los datos a la vista correcta?

Comment: Por otro lado antes de mandar a la vista has esto: `dd($users);` y verifica si te retorna valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('users.index', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);
```

fíjate que en nombre de la vista este bien pero asi te debería funcionar sin problema

Comment: La consulta que tiene el OP también funciona, de hecho la que el tiene ordena de forma descendente los resultados

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por la ayuda.
La solucion final y que recomiendo es que reincien "laragon" o cualquier gestor que tengan ya sea xammp u otro, el error nunca lo supe, pero se arreglo reinciando laragon. Creo que no se cargaba la información por alguna razon. Realmente no modifique nada en el codigo, estaba todo correctamente